# Angular momentum contained in E&M fields

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, angular-momentum, poynting-vector

I am trying to do this question as a prep for my quals and find my solution too simplistic. I fear I am missing something important.

"Iron atoms (atomic mass 56) contain two free electron spins that can align with an external magnetic field. An iron wire 3 cm long and 1 mm in diameter is suspended vertically and is free to rotate about its axis. A strong magnetic field parallel to the wire's axis is applied. How large is the resulting change in its angular velocity? The density of iron is 8 $g/cm^3$."

I assume the axis of the wire is in the z direction, so that $\vec{B} = B \hat{z}$. By using Faraday's law $ \oint \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dl} = -\frac{d}{dt} \int \vec{B} \cdot \vec{da}$ on a circular loop in the xy-plane, I get that the electric field produced by applying the external magnetic field is $\vec{E} \sim \hat{\phi}$. Hence the Poynting vector would be $\vec{S} \sim \hat{\phi} \times \hat{z} = \hat{r}$ and the angular momentum change in the fields would be 0 since $\vec{L} \sim \vec{r} \times \vec{S}$.

I feel this approach is missing something, especially since I am not using any of the information that's given in the problem and all the other problems never give information that is not useful to solve them. Am I missing something?

Comment: Why don't you just calculate the number of spins in the piece of wire? The field is strong so you can assume all spins will align along the field. So you can calculate the angular momentum associated with the spins.

Comment: I did not think of your solution because it's too simple and my mind has a way of overcomplicating things. Thank you!

Comment: No worry. I'm used to this. Believe me :)